# grails derived property creating column in database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using grails 2.4.4.

I have the domain

```
class Post {
    Integer nbrOfFavorites
    static hasMany = [
        favorites : Favorite
    ]

    static mappings = {
        nbrOfFavorites formula: '(select count(1) from favorite f where (f.post_id = id))'
    }
}
```

The problem is that nbrOfFavorites is being created in the database, so retrieving it doesn't take into account the formula.

Is there something wrong in my syntax ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you dropped your database and started again after adding the formula entry? If you ran the app before adding the `formula` option then the schema may have stored that variable against that table???

Comment: I'll try this in my dev environment,but i can't do it in my production environment, is there an alternative ?

Comment: database-migration plugin should handle it - http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration... if it is the problem.

Comment: I created a new database and still have the same problem, I'm using `runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4"` if this is relevant

Comment: have you tried count(*)

Comment: I tried it now,still have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a typo in the syntax. Change `mappings` to `mapping`, like:

```
static mapping = {
    nbrOfFavorites formula: '(select count(1) from favorite f where (f.post_id = id))'
}
```

Ref# [Grails Domain: mapping](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/mapping.html)

Comment: That was it!!! I don't understand how the delete cascade was working with this typo all over my project :|. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try adding this field as a transient to the domain object:

```
class Post {
Integer nbrOfFavorites
static hasMany = [
    favorites : Favorite
]

static mappings = {
    nbrOfFavorites formula: '(select count(1) from favorite f where (f.post_id = id))'
}

static transients = ['nbrOfFavorites']
}
```